# Pandas Dataframe - I cant retrieve values by index after filtering df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, filtering, series

**1. The starting point**

I create a df that i get by filtering ->  **df4 = df[df['Name Block DWG'] == block]**

The partial output of df4 is:

```
.
.
.

[0 rows x 21 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name Block DWG, Name Revit  Familie:Type, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, Tiefe dwg, Breite dwg, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s]
Index: []

[0 rows x 21 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name Block DWG, Name Revit  Familie:Type, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, Tiefe dwg, Breite dwg, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s]
Index: []

[0 rows x 21 columns]
   Name Block DWG      Name Revit  Familie:Type  s      s  \
11          NS-HV  NSHV-Abgangsfeld:Abgangsfeld  1  44727   
12          NS-HV          NSHV-LS-Feld:LS-Feld  1  44727   
13          NS-HV                      Schrank:  1  44727   
14          NS-HV                      Schrank:  1  44727   

                                      s   s        s    s    s   s  ...  \
11  ?, Clearance im Script deaktivieren  ET  600x600  0.6  0.6 NaN  ...   
12                                    ?  ET  600x400  0.6  0.4 NaN  ...   
13                            QS/HB/NHS  ET  800x400  0.4  0.8 NaN  ...   
14                            QS/HB/NHS  ET  800x400  0.4  0.6 NaN  ...   

   Breite dwg     s                             s  \
11        0.6  Nein  Mitte/unterer Rand der Tiefe   
12        0.4  Nein  Mitte/unterer Rand der Tiefe   
13        0.8  Nein  Mitte/unterer Rand der Tiefe   
14        0.6  Nein  Mitte/unterer Rand der Tiefe   

                               s    s    s      s   s   s   s  
11  Mitte/unterer Rand der Tiefe  NaN  NaN -540.0 NaN NaN NaN  
12  Mitte/unterer Rand der Tiefe  NaN  NaN -540.0 NaN NaN NaN  
13  Mitte/unterer Rand der Tiefe  NaN  NaN -360.0 NaN NaN NaN  
14  Mitte/unterer Rand der Tiefe  NaN  NaN -360.0 NaN NaN NaN  


[0 rows x 21 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name Block DWG, Name Revit  Familie:Type, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, Tiefe dwg, Breite dwg, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s]
Index: []

[0 rows x 21 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name Block DWG, Name Revit  Familie:Type, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, Tiefe dwg, Breite dwg, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s]
Index: []

.
.
.
```

**2. What should the result be?**

```
11          NS-HV      
12          NS-HV             
13          NS-HV
14          NS-HV
```

**3. What was my output so far?**

I want to get the ['Name Block DWG'] column-values in the case that the value is not empty.

What works is if I go 1 level deeper by using: **df4 = df4['Name Block DWG']**

Then the output looks like:

```
.
.
.

Series([], Name: Name Block DWG, dtype: object)
Series([], Name: Name Block DWG, dtype: object)
11    NS-HV
12    NS-HV
13    NS-HV
14    NS-HV
Series([], Name: Name Block DWG, dtype: object)
Series([], Name: Name Block DWG, dtype: object)

.
.
.
```

**4. What is the problem?**

I can not get the values described in **2. What should the result be?**,  when I  use any index (it does not matter what index I try) that is the error:  **print(df4['Name Block DWG'][0])**

```
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

I already have tried a lot of things like creating new columns df4.columns = ['Name Block DWG' ....

/  index df4 = df4['Name Block DWG'].reset_index(drop=True)

/   .iloc

/   .name

/   .values

/    .to_list

/    .values.to_list()

/   .to_dict

/  in any combination you can imagine

I just cant get it to work, maybe my question isnt even the right one ?

Any help would be appeciated.

Comment: Your question is too long and complicated. Please reduce its size so it can be better understand

Comment: I have posted a simplyfied version of the question (here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075341/i-cant-retrieve-values-by-index-in-filtered-dataframe). I still want to keep this one as reference or for additional info I can give directly by linking this question here!