# I cant retrieve values by index in filtered DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, filter, series

Since the last time I posted this question I got a comment saying that my description is too complicated, this now is a simplified version:
(here you can find the more complicated question -> [Pandas Dataframe - I cant retrieve values by index after filtering df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070316/pandas-dataframe-i-cant-retrieve-values-by-index-after-filtering-df))

**1. What is my output?**

**df4 = df4['Name Block DWG']**

Then the output looks like:

```
.
.
.

Series([], Name: Name Block DWG, dtype: object)
Series([], Name: Name Block DWG, dtype: object)
11    NS-HV
12    NS-HV
13    NS-HV
14    NS-HV
Series([], Name: Name Block DWG, dtype: object)
Series([], Name: Name Block DWG, dtype: object)

.
.
.
```

**df4 = df4[['Name Block DWG']]**

Then the output looks like:

```
.
.
.

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name Block DWG]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name Block DWG]
Index: []
   Name Block DWG
11          NS-HV
12          NS-HV
13          NS-HV
14          NS-HV

.
.
.
```

**2. What should the result be?**

```
11          NS-HV      
12          NS-HV             
13          NS-HV
14          NS-HV
```

I just cant get it to work, maybe my question isnt even the right one ?

Any help would be appeciated.

Comment: Please add a sample of your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your dataframe so I cannot simulate.

Try instead using double square brackets:

```
df4 = df4[['Name Block DWG']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately it does not work. I tried to recreate a simplyfied version of my df (for testing purposes) , the funny thing is that it behaves different then the 'real' df. I am reading a excel file and the script is complicated, so I dont know how much of a use it would be to share it